# Diffrentiation Under The Sign of Integral sin and cos

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I know that: 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)f(x)dx$$

What can I say about $f$?

Comment: $f$ is orthogonal to $\sin(x-\frac\pi4)$ (in $L^2([0,\pi/2])$) by using linearity and the identity $\cos x -\sin x = -\sqrt 2 \sin(x-\frac\pi4)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2}sin(x)f(x)dx=\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2}cos(x)f(x)dx$$
$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2}\left(sin(x)-cos(x)\right)f(x)dx=0$$
$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2}sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})f(x)dx=0$$
$$\int_{y=-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}sin(y)f(y+\frac{\pi}{4})dy=0$$
Let's decompose $f$ in two parts, symmetric and antisymmetric w.r.t. $y=\pi/4$
$$f(y+\frac{\pi}{4})=f^+(y+\frac{\pi}{4})+f^-(y+\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{f(y+\frac{\pi}{4})+f(-y+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}+\frac{f(y+\frac{\pi}{4})-f(-y+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}$$
Now:
$$\int_{y=-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}sin(y)f^+(y+\frac{\pi}{4})dy+\int_{y=-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}sin(y)f^-(y+\frac{\pi}{4})dy=0$$
$$0+2\int_{y=0}^{\pi/4}sin(y)f^-(y+\frac{\pi}{4})dy=0$$
$$\int_{y=0}^{\pi/4}sin(y)f^-(y+\frac{\pi}{4})dy=0$$
The symmetric part is free, since it respects the given condition in any case, while the antisymmetric part must satisfy the last equation.